Anime about a group of kids who controls each member of a mecha and the boy controls its heart
I don't know where I saw this anime, but I remember it faintly and this doubt triggers everytime I see a mecha anime.
I remember a little boy wandering in the woods maybe with his sister? And he found a dead giant or robot. I don't remember all of it but he got a "cube" or something that seemed to be the robot's heart.
Later on the episode, their parents and mother get attacked and their "planet, moon, idk" are wreaked in havoc. Their mother and father send the children to Earth(?). On Earth, there is a political or royal government and some type of assembly going on.
Fast forwarding some steps... The kids end up finding other kids with special abilities and they together fight a evil lady with a robot and special ability too. On this part, each kid controls a member of the big robot and the kid controls his "heart" with the "cube" he got from the ancient robot.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vnP5Sxd49Y - Visions of Escaflowne has them finding a dragon heart and using it to power a mecha

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBK/BRNK? Lots of mentions of hearts and mechas.

@Valorum It was Bubuki/Buranki!!! The first episode is clear on my mind!! Thanks a lot for the answer!! How can I confirm on the post?

You can confirm by "accepting" Valorum's answer down below (click the checkmark on the left of his answer, just below the voting buttons).

This is BBK/BRNK (AKA Bubuki/Buranki)

Azuma Kazuki is a young boy living with his family on Treasure Island
(宝島), a floating island several thousand feet above Earth that is
inhabited by giant sentient robots called Buranki (ブランキ), all of which
are "sleeping". However, several of the Buranki are killed to wake up,
forcing Migiwa Kazuki, his mother, to send Azuma, his identical twin
sister Kaoruko, and their father down to Earth and is killed in a
Buranki named Oubu for safety, leaving her behind.
Ten years later, Azuma, returning to a post-apocalyptic Shinjuku is
captured by the authorities, but was saved by his childhood friend
Kogane Asabuki, a user of a sentient weapon known as Bubuki (ブブキ),
which also forms a Buranki's limbs. Discovering he is a Bubuki-user
himself with the Heart of Oubu, Azuma and Kogane unite with three
other Bubuki-users: Hiiragi Nono, Kinoa Ōgi and Shizuru Taneomi, to
work together to seek and revive the lost Oubu, and discover the
hidden truths behind the Buranki and the mysterious Reoko Banryū's
tyranny over the post-apocalyptic Japan with her own Buranki: Entei.




